# Fluent NHibernation unique string mapping (Ignoring Duplicates)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, unique

I have this table
id (int,pk,ai),
word(varchar 25)

Lets say that I am allowing users to add new single words to my database.
I want Nhibernate to skip adding new word if it is already exists.
How can I map it in fluent? Is that doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapping:

```
Map(x => x.Word).Unique(); // just to make sure it is unique
```

code:

```
void AddWords(ICollection<string> words)
{
    var existingWords = session.QueryOver<UniqueWord>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(w => w.Word).In(words)
        .Select(w => w.Word)
        .List<string>();

    foreach(var word in words.Except(existingWords))
    {
        session.Save(new UniqueWord(word));
    }
    session.Flush();
}
```